# UBUNTU 16.04 Getting libx86emu x86emu-demo to work?

Tags: assembly, x86, emulation

Does anyone know how to get libx86emu x86emu-demo to work?

https://github.com/wfeldt/libx86emu

```
Test.obj  00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F
000000B0  00 0A 00 00 55 8B EC 51 C7 45 FC 00 00 00 00 8B 
000000C0  45 FC 50 E8 09 00 00 00 83 C4 04 33 C0 8B E5 5D 
000000D0  C3 55 8B EC B8 01 00 00 00 5D C3 00 07 00 00 00 

B4: 55                      push   ebp
B5: 8b ec                   mov    ebp,esp
B7: 51                      push   ecx
B8: c7 45 fc 00 00 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4],0x0
BF: 8b 45 fc                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4]
C2: 50                      push   eax
C3: e8 09 00 00 00          call   0x1d
C8: 83 c4 04                add    esp,0x4
CB: 33 c0                   xor    eax,eax
CD: 8b e5                   mov    esp,ebp
CF: 5d                      pop    ebp
D0: c3                      ret
D1: 55                      push   ebp
D2: 8b ec                   mov    ebp,esp
D4: b8 01 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x1
D9: 5d                      pop    ebp
DA: c3                      ret
```

./x86emu-demo -l 0 -s 0xB4 Test.obj

I need to be able to execute x86 machine code similar to the above sample. libx86emu decodes and executes the first three instructions then decodes the fourth instruction incorrectly. I only need to be able to emulate 32-bit x86, I don't need any OS support.

Only about half of the libx86emu x86test regression tests pass.

## Here is the actual execution trace

```
eax 00000000, ebx 00000000, ecx 00000000, edx 00000000
esi 00000000, edi 00000000, ebp 00000000, esp 00000000
cs 0000, ss 0000, ds 0000, es 0000, fs 0000, gs 0000
eip 000000b4, eflags 00000002
x [000000b4] = 55
w [0000fffe] = 0000
0 0000:00b4 55                       push bp

eax 00000000, ebx 00000000, ecx 00000000, edx 00000000
esi 00000000, edi 00000000, ebp 00000000, esp 0000fffe
cs 0000, ss 0000, ds 0000, es 0000, fs 0000, gs 0000
eip 000000b5, eflags 00000002
x [000000b5] = 8b
x [000000b6] = ec
1 0000:00b5 8bec                     mov bp,sp

eax 00000000, ebx 00000000, ecx 00000000, edx 00000000
esi 00000000, edi 00000000, ebp 0000fffe, esp 0000fffe
cs 0000, ss 0000, ds 0000, es 0000, fs 0000, gs 0000
eip 000000b7, eflags 00000002
x [000000b7] = 51
w [0000fffc] = 0000
2 0000:00b7 51                       push cx

eax 00000000, ebx 00000000, ecx 00000000, edx 00000000
esi 00000000, edi 00000000, ebp 0000fffe, esp 0000fffc
cs 0000, ss 0000, ds 0000, es 0000, fs 0000, gs 0000
eip 000000b8, eflags 00000002
x [000000b8] = c7
x [000000b9] = 45
x [000000ba] = fc
x [000000bb] = 0000
w [0000fffc] = 0000
3 0000:00b8 c745fc0000               mov [di-04],0000

eax 00000000, ebx 00000000, ecx 00000000, edx 00000000
esi 00000000, edi 00000000, ebp 0000fffe, esp 0000fffc
cs 0000, ss 0000, ds 0000, es 0000, fs 0000, gs 0000
eip 000000bd, eflags 00000002
x [000000bd] = 00
x [000000be] = 00
r [00000000] = 4c
w [00000000] = 4c
4 0000:00bd 0000                     add [bx+si],al
* no proper code
```

Comment: If I had to guess, libx86emu is emulating your code in a virtual 16-bit real mode environment and as a result likely it decoded the first 4 instructions as `push bp`
`mov bp,sp`
`push cx`
`mov word [di-0x4],0x0`
`add [bx+si],al`

Comment: @MichaelPetch That was my guess too. I will search the code to see how to force 32-bit mode. Test.obj is a binary obj file that decodes to the 32-bit instructions shown below it. It was generated with a visual C++ compiler. I only want to the to run as-is in 32-bit mode. I don't need any functionality from the operating system. –

Comment: @MichaelPetch It looks like our suspicions may be confirmed by the increment of eip 000000b7 to eip 000000bd being two rather than four bytes. –

Comment: Yes I believed that to be the case all along. My question is why do you need to use libx86emu. Are you looking at integrating this is into an OS, or are you just trying to run arbitrary 32-bit code? If so why not just compile it for your OS (Linux? Windows? I'm wondering if libx86emu is an incorrect solution to some other problem you are trying to solve? (An [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))

Comment: @MichaelPetch I need to run arbitrary 32-bit X86 code (compiled with Visual Studio) under UBUNTU. I am making a program that analyzes 32-bit X86 machine code. Visual Studio produces much simpler code, having the semantic essence of the original "C" code. The code that GCC produces is much more convoluted. The emulated code need not have any OS support.

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/wfeldt/libx86emu/issues/25

The author of libx86emu "Steffen Winterfeldt"
updated: libx86emu/demo/x86emu-demo.c
so that it now has a "32-bit mode" command line parameter.

Previously the code executed in the default 16-bit mode.